# Double binding in the same statement in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have 2 ng-repeats in a table as follows:

```
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="header in headerdata">{{header}}</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td ng-repeat="header in headerdata">{{row.header}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here i want the header inside the {{row.header}} to be bound with the value in the header that comes from the headerdata in the  tags.

I tried something like {{row.(header)}} but it would return a function and throws a console error.

How would i do it?

**Update:**

My row data is a `json` data and my headerdata is an `array` that contains the headers which is also the keys in the data. The reason i am doing it this way is because the order in my row data is not proper.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: What does row look like.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is headerdata an array inside of the row object? Is headerdata a completely seperate array? Think about what you're trying to do here 'row.header' where row is an object and header is something in an array. This cannot work. Need more info about what youre trying to do.

Comment: headerdata and data are 2 different scope variables. But the keys in data are present in headerdata in a particular order which i am trying to follow to display in my table

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand, i'll recap. So your headerdata array is in some order that you want to display this information that is correct. The data array is not in the correct order. So you are attempting to use the 'headerdata' order to display the 'data' data.

It sounds like you can make use of angular filters, specifically orderBy : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

If you can't find a filter that works for you, then you should reorder the data array in a custom filter or in your controller to how you need it rather than trying to do this weird thing you are trying to do.

Comment: actually this worked for me. <td ng-repeat="header in headerdata" ng-bind="row.{{header}}"></td>

Comment: I recommend use an array access notation as this works native in js row[header]

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that ng-repeat creates new scopes for each iterations of it.

You need this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td ng-repeat="header in headerdata">{{$parent.row.header}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It does create a new scope, but it's a child scope so you can access all the properties from the parent via prototype inheritance. That shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Prototype inheritance won't work when `header` has been overriden, using `$parent` in this instance is a reasonable approach. To make use of inheritance the `ng-repeat` variable would need to be changed.